# Mongodb aggregate query $skip $limit issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a query I call on from my app, to provide me with paged results from my db

```
const query = [
  {
    "$match" : {
      "$or" : [
        { "expires_at" : { "$gt" : moment().toISOString() }},
        { "expires_at" : null }
      ],
      "vendor_category" : {
        "$nin" : ignoredCategories
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": models.retailers.collection.name,
      "localField": "retailer",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "retailer"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": models.categories.collection.name,
      "localField": "category",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "category"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "category.popularity" : -1,
      ...sortBy
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$retailer" },
  { "$unwind": "$category" },
  { "$skip" : skip },
  { "$limit" : limit }
]
```

This mostly works, my two `$lookup` and `$unwind` objects join the other collections to the results and my `$sort` object correctly sorts the root query by the products category popularity.

However my `$match` object only returns about 18 (of 72) results. Which would be fine except that when i run `const total = await models.products.countDocuments(query[0].$match)`, so count the documents using that match query, i get 72. So There is a mismatch between the two.

So what is happening to the rest of the results? Am i doing something wrong in this query? This is definitely the first aggregate query i've written, so maybe i'm just completely missing something. Any tips / questions / optimizations are welcomed! If you need any more info let me know.

**Edit**
Here is an example of the match query expanded. When i was using `Model.find` with this it was working fine, but since i've been isolating parts of the query this seems to be the culprit. The intent is to only pull results that have an expire time greater than the current time, or the field is null. The data comes from a scraper and sometimes i don't have the expires data. I also exclude a string of categories, this is a safeguard from displaying items that make it through the scraper but i don't want on the site.

```
$match : {
       $or : [
         { expires_at : { $gt : moment().toISOString() }},
         { expires_at : null }
      ],
      vendor_category : {
        $nin : [ 'ID-6',   'ID-8', 'ID-283', 'ID-288', 'ID-354', 'ID-513', 'ID-654', 'ID-659', 'ID-33', 'ID-450', 'ID-497',  'ID-59', 'ID-404', 'ID-337']
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible some of category or retailer do not exist in the another collection. Of yes the `$unwind` is the cause of problem here.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/ doesn't answer the question yet worth reading. How do you know the first stage returns "about 18 results" ?

Comment: So I take it, your question is only about the $match query? There are some slight implementation differences between a regular and an aggregation query, which might interfere here. Can you give us an example of the ignoredCategories? Also, are you sure the "expires_at" will always be "null", or can it also just not be set at all ?

Comment: @BenSower i updated the question giving a bit more context about this. When i completely remove the match query, i get all my results, paging works correctly. Also when i leave the vendor_category query in there it seems to work fine too. So the `$or` object seems to be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after digging and digging I found a [github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1599) that solved my problem and hopefully this will help others in the future. When using `Model.aggregate`, Mongoose does not cast it's arguments.

If you are looking to match with a date using `Model.aggregate` you HAVE to wrap the date in `new Date()`.

Originally i was doing this which didn't work: `{ expires_at : { $gte : moment().toISOString() }}`

And changed it to this, which works: `{ expires_at : { $gte : new Date(moment().toISOString()) }}`

Comment: That's what I meant with "slight implementation differences". Another one is the handling of ObjectIds, where you can sometimes run into problems if you don't pass it in a way the aggregation framework understands. Please also mark your answer as complete then :-)

Comment: Just wanted to say that you are totally right and i appreciate you setting me down that path. Once I started isolating the different objects they were definitely different which helped me get everything sorted. Thanks man!